# Third party cookies and gtag

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, gtag.js, third-party-cookies

When user set:

```
gtag("consent", "update", {
    ad_storage: "granted",
    analytics_storage: "granted"
});
```

as consent settings on our website, following warnings are thrown in google chrome console:

[image]

and

[image]

I've noticed that this happens only when ad_storage is "granted", analytics_storage can be set in any option and warnings are not shown.

What do we have to do to fix these warnings, if we have? Change some settings in google ads or google manager, something else? Or this issue will be fixed by google itself, since these are google cookies?

I've asked about this in google tag manager and google analytics help forums but did not get any reply yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got answer from google chrome engineering manager at github: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/privacy-sandbox-dev-support/discussions/173#discussioncomment-7393749

In short: "... I think you can ignore the warnings for this specific set of cookies. On our end, we're thinking about how we can reduce the noisiness of these warnings and make them more actionable. ..."

**So, warnings for these cookies can be ignored.**